# Finding roots using the cubic formula

Tags: roots, problem-solving, cubics

I have obtained the cubic formula from google, for some generic cubic function:
$$ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0,$$
it is expressed:

\begin{align*}
x&=\sqrt[3]{\left(-\frac{b^3}{27a^3}+\frac{bc}{6a^2}-\frac{d}{2a}\right)+\sqrt{\left(-\frac{b^3}{27a^3}+\frac{bc}{6a^2}-\frac{d}{2a}\right)^2+\left(\frac{c}{3a}-\frac{b^2}{9a^2}\right)^3}}\\& +
\sqrt[3]{\left(-\frac{b^3}{27a^3}+\frac{bc}{6a^2}-\frac{d}{2a}\right)-\sqrt{\left(-\frac{b^3}{27a^3}+\frac{bc}{6a^2}-\frac{d}{2a}\right)^2+\left(\frac{c}{3a}-\frac{b^2}{9a^2}\right)^3}} \\& -\frac{b}{3a},
\end{align*}
I am actually considering when $a=C,b=-B,c=0,d=0$
$$B,C\in \mathbb{R},$$
$$x\geq 0,$$
So the relation becomes:
\begin{align*}
x&=\sqrt[3]{\frac{B^3}{27C^3}+\sqrt{\left(\frac{B^3}{27C^3}\right)^2+\left(\frac{B^2}{9C^2}\right)^3}}\\& +
\sqrt[3]{\frac{B^3}{27C^3}-\sqrt{\left(\frac{B^3}{27C^3}\right)^2+\left(\frac{B^2}{9C^2}\right)^3}}\\& +\frac{B}{3C},
\end{align*}

---

## Second Attempt at the solution

---

Going back to the original expression:
\begin{align*}
x&=\sqrt[3]{\frac{B^3}{27C^3}+\sqrt{\left(\frac{B^3}{27C^3}\right)^2+\left(\frac{B^2}{9C^2}\right)^3}}\\& +
\sqrt[3]{\frac{B^3}{27C^3}-\sqrt{\left(\frac{B^3}{27C^3}\right)^2+\left(\frac{B^2}{9C^2}\right)^3}}\\& +\frac{B}{3C},
\end{align*}
Simplifying the terms in the square root gives:
\begin{align*}
x&=\sqrt[3]{\frac{B^3}{27C^3}+\sqrt{\left(\frac{2B^6}{729C^6}\right)}}\\& +
\sqrt[3]{\frac{B^3}{27C^3}-\sqrt{\left(\frac{2B^6}{729C^6}\right)}}\\& +\frac{B}{3C},
\end{align*}
Given:
$$\sqrt{\left(\frac{2B^6}{729C^6}\right)}=\pm\frac{\sqrt{2}B^3}{27C^3}$$
\begin{align*}
x=\sqrt[3]{\frac{B^3}{27C^3}(1\pm\sqrt{2})} +
\sqrt[3]{\frac{B^3}{27C^3}(1\mp \sqrt{2})} +\frac{B}{3C},
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
x=\frac{B}{3C}((1\pm\sqrt{2})^{1/3} +(1\mp \sqrt{2})^{1/3} +1),
\end{align*}
I have been told that the roots are $$x=0, x=\frac{B}{C};$$
I cant see that this final expression would reduce to $$x=\frac{B}{C},$$
or $$x=0,$$
regardless of my choice of combo with the $\pm$, any further advice on what to do would be appreciated :)

---

## Initial Attempt (Incorrect)

---

I have attempted to find the roots as follows; starting by cubing the whole relation:
\begin{align*}
x^3&=\frac{B^3}{27C^3}+\sqrt{\left(\frac{B^3}{27C^3}\right)^2+\left(\frac{B^2}{9C^2}\right)^3}\\& +
\frac{B^3}{27C^3}-\sqrt{\left(\frac{B^3}{27C^3}\right)^2+\left(\frac{B^2}{9C^2}\right)^3}\\& +\frac{B^3}{27C^3},
\end{align*}
Grouping like terms:
\begin{align*}
x^3&=\frac{3B^3}{27C^3}+\sqrt{\left(\frac{B^3}{27C^3}\right)^2+\left(\frac{B^2}{9C^2}\right)^3}\\&
-\sqrt{\left(\frac{B^3}{27C^3}\right)^2+\left(\frac{B^2}{9C^2}\right)^3}\\& ,
\end{align*}
and now expanding brackets within the square root and putting over a common denominator we get:
\begin{align*}
x^3&=\frac{3B^3}{27C^3}+\sqrt{\frac{2B^6}{729C^6}}-\sqrt{\frac{2B^6}{729C^6}}\\& ,
\end{align*}
$B$ and $C$ are either positive or negative constants but due to the even powers within the square roots, they are strictly positive and thus will return a real result. Taking these terms to give either a both positive or both negative result we would get:
\begin{align*}
x^3&=\frac{3B^3}{27C^3},
\end{align*}
So taking the cube root we get:
\begin{align*}
x&=\frac{\sqrt[3]{3}}{3}\frac{B}{C},
\end{align*}
Now, if these square rooted terms were different in signs we would get:
\begin{align*}
x^3&=\frac{3B^3}{27C^3}\pm2\sqrt{\frac{2B^6}{729C^6}} ,
\end{align*}
or:
\begin{align*}
x^3&=\frac{3B^3}{27C^3}\pm2\sqrt{2}\frac{B^3}{27C^3} ,
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
x^3&=\frac{B^3}{27C^3}(3\pm 2\sqrt{2})
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
x&=\frac{B}{C}\frac{\sqrt[3]{(3\pm 2\sqrt{2})}}{3}
\end{align*}
I have been told that the roots are $$x=0, x=\frac{B}{C};$$
Clearly these are not the roots that I have obtained, but I cannot see what I have done wrong? Any advice on how I can successfully manipulate the cubic formula would be appreciated :)

Comment: Under the square roots sign, you should have a minus sign rather than a plus sign between the two terms, shouldn't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is a problem with the signs,
For $b=-B,a=C,c=0,d=0$ we get:
\begin{align*}
x&=\sqrt[3]{\left(\frac{B^3}{27C^3}\right)+\sqrt{\left(\frac{B^3}{27C^3}\right)^2+\left(-\frac{B^2}{9a^2}\right)^3}}\\& +
\sqrt[3]{\left(\frac{B^3}{27C^3}\right)-\sqrt{\left(\frac{B^3}{27C^3}\right)^2+\left(-\frac{B^2}{9a^2}\right)^3}} \\& +\frac{B}{3C},
\end{align*}
The terms within the square root clearly become 0 and then:
$$\sqrt[3]{\frac{B^3}{27C^3}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{B^3}{27C^3}}+\frac{B}{3C},$$
$$x=\frac{B}{C},$$

Answer (score 2):

The problem begins when you start “by cubing the whole relation”; you seem to think that, if $x=y+z+w$, then $x^3=y^3+z^3+w^3$, which is not true.

Comment: Thanks! I have edited my initial post and included a second attempt, without that stupid assumption, I still cant seem to get to my roots though